# Android: Creating service on different process, that registers receiver that starts intentservice

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-intentservice

I'm building an application that one of the things it does is listening to several android broadcasts on the phone (like ringermodechanged etc.. ) and sends them to a server. 
The part that does this thing is crucial to the application, and I need that even when the app crushes this part would continue working.

I came with the following solution:

In mainactivity - Start Service on different process, that registers BroadcastReceiver and when each broadcast is received - call intentservice to report it. 
Additionally, create another BroadcastReceiver that listens to boot completed, and starts the service mentioned above.

Would that seem like a reasonable solution?